# Mockito Rest End Point Testing - Compare List with quotes

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-mvc, mockito

Though my tests should be complete and going green. It is a really small issue, which I need help with.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:integrator-rest.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProjectBuilderControllerTest {

@Mock
private ProjectBuilderController projectBuilderControllerMock;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

@Test
public void loadDependencyListMockTest() throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add("spring-core-3.0.1");
    result.add("spring-webmvc-4.2.1");
    result.add("spring-test-4.0.1");
    result.add("junit-4.1");

    mockMvc.perform(get("/projectbuilder/dependencyList")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    mockMvc.perform(get("/projectbuilder/dependencyList").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(5)))
                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.equalTo((result))));
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = null;
}

}
```

I simply want to add/remove so the test passes. Here is the link to the xml file from which I am loading my dependency list and returns the list.

Basically the loadDependencyList() method loads a list of dependencies from the XML File and returns the list of dependencies, I'm just testing that the returned list is consistent.

THE TEST IS NOW PASSING! THE ISSUE WAS THE ORDER OF RETURN WAS INCORRECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Mockito does not care whether if the elements of your List which are Strings to be in quotes or not, it compares it anyway and the test passes. The order in which you are comparing makes a difference. Hence if you think your issue is that of quotes/no-quotes you have another issue.

Eg: I was expecting

```
<["junit","jax-rs","spring-mvc","spring-context"]>
```

and if it returned

```
<[junit,jax-rs,spring-mvc,spring-context]>
```

The test should pass. Remembers, the order matters.